# Spring flyway configuration: cannot find placeholders when running sql

Tags: spring, postgresql, gradle, flyway

I am trying to run `gradlew flywayMigrate`, and the application chrashes when running a recurring migration with the error

> Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No value provided for placeholder expressions: ${dbLinkHost}, ${dbLinkPassword}, ${dbLinkSid}, ${dbLinkUser}.  Check your configuration!

The variables are configured like this in `application.yml`:

```
flyway:
  placeholders:
    dbLinkHost: ...
    dbLinkSid: ...
    dbLinkUser: ...
    dbLinkPassword: ...
```

And I try to access them like this in the sql file:

```
'${dbLinkHost}'
```

Does anyone know why the declarations in `application.yml` don`t seem to be accessible here?

Answer (score 1):

As a result of [Spring Boot Issue #9896 - Move Flyway configuration properties to spring.flyway](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9896) and commit [`f9e3163`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/f9e316306aaff3a9dbdf64511762ac0919ae0f3b), starting with v2.0.0.M4, Flyway configuration properties in your application properties start with `spring.flyway`.  To configure Flyway placeholders, for example:

```
spring:
  flyway:
    placeholders:
      dbLinkHost: ...
      dbLinkSid: ...
      dbLinkUser: ...
      dbLinkPassword: ...
```

In Spring Boot versions before v2.0.0.M4 such as the recently-released v1.5.14.RELEASE, Flyway configuration properties start with `flyway`.